# Is it possible to create a list where types in it cannot be changed, but the value itself can?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if it exists a way to create a list where variables inside could be changed to  other variables but exclusively if they are of the same type.

for instance

```
a=[0, 1.0, 'blabla']
a[0] = 0 # is possible
a[1] = 2. # is possible
a[2] = 'albalb' # is possible
a[0] = 1.2 # is not possible
a[1] = 'no' # is not possible
a[2] = 1 # is not possible
```

I cannot use tuple to do that because it is immutable.

My goal is to create a list where the number of value in it can vary, so append, insert and pop will be useful. I also want slicing available in order to select a part of the list.
At the end, the list will contain my own classes which describe neuronal models. I have different models possible, so different classes.
With the list, I would like to do what we can do with Lists but I don't want the type of a variable in the list to change, except if I insert a neuron at a position. In that case, every variable after that position is shifted too the right.

for instance:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 0

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 1

class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 2

class D():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 3

MyList =  [A(),B(),C()]
print([M.A for M in MyList])
#insert
MyList.insert(1,D())
print([M.A for M in MyList])
#slicing
MyList2 = MyList[1:3]
print([M.A for M in MyList2])
#replace if the variable is the same type that the variable of the list to replace
MyList[0] = A()
print([M.A for M in MyList])
#So this should not be possible 
MyList[0] = B()
print([M.A for M in MyList])
```

I would like something really close from the List object, so I expected that it could already exist.

Comment: You'll have to implement a custom class that implements `__setitem__` and does appropriate type checking there.

Comment: What about slices? Should `a[:] = [1, 'oops', 'ok']` be checked too? What about `a[:] = [1, 'ok']`? You'll need to gather all the specs and then create your own implementation (which can inherit from `list`).

Comment: I would [check this out](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/#UserList/UserDict:_lists_and_dictionaries_that_are_actually_extensible)

Comment: Consider using a class and separate attributes for each value, rather than a list. `a = Foo(0, 1.0, 'blabla')`, with appropriate type-checking for each attribute.

Comment: I think @chepner has the right idea, can you share some more background for this?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please give a concrete use-case or explain more clearly what you are really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1** Wrap all methods which modify the list in-place and override `__setitem__()`

```
class RewritingLockedTypeList(list):
    def __init__(self, original_list):
        super().__init__(original_list)
        self.types = [type(n) for n in original_list]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.types[key] != type(value):
            raise TypeError(f"Value at index {key} should be {self.types[key]}!")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)


def wrap_method(method_name):
    orig_method = getattr(RewritingLockedTypeList, method_name)

    def new_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = orig_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.types = [type(n) for n in self]
        return result

    setattr(RewritingLockedTypeList, method_name, new_method)


for method in ["append", "clear", "extend", "insert", "pop", "remove", "reverse", "sort"]:
    wrap_method(method)
```

**Solution 2** Override all methods which modify the list in-place and override `__setitem__()` too

```
class LockedTypeList(list):
    def __init__(self, original_list):
        super().__init__(original_list)
        self.types = [type(n) for n in original_list]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.types[key] != type(value):
            raise TypeError(f"Value at index {key} should be {self.types[key]}!")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.types[key]
        super().__delitem__(key)

    def append(self, thing):
        self.types.append(type(thing))
        super().append(thing)

    def clear(self):
        self.types.clear()
        super().clear()

    def extend(self, objects):
        self.types.extend(type(o) for o in objects)
        super().extend(objects)

    def insert(self, idx, obj):
        self.types.insert(idx, type(obj))
        super().insert(idx, obj)

    def pop(self, index=0):
        self.types.pop(index)
        super().pop(index)

    def remove(self, value):
        idx = self.index(value)
        self.pop(idx)

    def reverse(self):
        self.types.reverse()
        super().reverse()

    def sort(self, key=lambda n: n, reverse=False):
        super().sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)
        self.types = [type(n) for n in self]
```

The second solution is longer, but faster for long lists.

**Usage**

```
a=LockedTypeList([0, 1.0, 'blabla'])
```

But you maybe should think about using a class and properties with type checking instead of this ugly list.

Comment: This will fail after an append, delete, slice assignment, etc, etc.

Comment: And I guess that a **Type** error will make more sense than a Value Error (after all, you want to enforce the same type...)